# Disable "Allow Cognito to automatically send messages to verify and confirm - Recommended" on User Pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to disable the flag "Allow Cognito to automatically send messages to verify and confirm - Recommended" on the UpdateUserPool API of Cognito, but i can't find is is possible.

If there is a flag to disable the "Allow Cognito to automatically send messages to verify and confirm - Recommended" in the UpdateUserPool API of cognito.